# Simulate Click on Li in WebViewer FIlemaker

Tags: javascript, jquery, filemaker

I tried to simulate a click on li  or span if possible in the Webviewer of Filemaker. i can't use " in the script. This is the code, Thanks

```
<div class="blockLargeList borRad5">
​  <div class="formTopMp borRad5">​Rechercher une catégorie par navigation​</div>​
  <li data-idcat="1000009409">​…​</li>​
  <div class=​"prodUnitCttCat" id="categContent">​
    <h3>​Sélectionnez une catégorie :​</h3>​
    <div class=​"prodUnitCat">​
      <ul data-lvlcat=​"1">​
        <li data-idcat=​"340">​…​</li>​
        <li data-idcat="1000012702">​…​</li>​
        <li data-idcat="1000016184" class=​"prodUnitSelectCat">​
          <span>​ANIMALERIE​</span>​
          " (16)"
        <li data-idcat=​"1000017214">​…​</li>​
        <li data-idcat=​"1000009673">​…​</li>​
        <li data-idcat=​"1000002192">​…​</li>​
```

[code html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Q87.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "trying to simulate a click"? Are you trying to call a onClick javascript function when a user clicks a element in your webviewer or do you have a event in FileMaker that should fire a javascript function in the webviewer? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

To answer a part of your query:

To use quotation marks in your calculations in FileMaker you need to escape the quotation marks or replace them with single quotes:

```
<li data-idcat="1000016184" class=​"prodUnitSelectCat">​
```

should be

```
"<li data-idcat=\"1000016184\" class=​\"prodUnitSelectCat\">​"
```

or

```
"<li data-idcat='1000016184' class='prodUnitSelectCat'>​"
```

inside a FIleMaker calculation.

It is not quite clear what are you trying to do, but I think you are trying to pass the selected value back to FileMaker. The way to do it is by using fmp url format. This can trigger a script in the current file which can set a field to the result of the selection.